# I can't install Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15R at all

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, system-installation, dell

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04LTS, 64bit onto a Dell Inspiron 15R laptop.  I've shrunk down one of the windows partitions and even used GParted to format the vacant space as `ext4`.

However, the install disk simply  does not present any options when it comes to the partitioning step.  What I get is a non-responsive  blank table.

As well as the above, I've changed the BIOS settings so that USB emulation is disabled (as per [Can't install on Dell Inspiron 15R](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16077/cant-install-on-dell-inspiron-15r?rq=1)), and changed the SATA Operation setting to all three possible options.

Anyway, the install CD will bring up the trial version of Ubuntu, and if I open terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`, I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb4fd9215

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *       81920    29044735    14481408    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        29044736  1005142015   488048640    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1005154920  1953520064   474182572+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb4fd923d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    16775167     8386560   84  OS/2 hidden C: drive
```

If I type `sudo parted -l`, I get:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVT-75A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary  fat16        diag
 2      41.9MB  14.9GB  14.8GB  primary  ntfs         boot
 3      14.9GB  515GB   500GB   primary  ntfs
 4      515GB   1000GB  486GB   primary  ext4

Model: ATA SAMSUNG SSD PM83 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8589MB  8588MB  primary

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

I've also tried a Kubuntu 12.04 and Linux Mint install disks, with the same problem.

I'm completely lost here.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with my new inspiron 17R. Tried both 10.04 and 12.04. Resolved issue after reading this thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003675

"If the disk has been used in RAID, it has raid meta data remains. In this case ubuntu ignores it thinking you are using it in a raid array.

If you ARE NOT using any RAID, remove the meta data from live mode with:
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda"

Not sure why my drive had RAID meta data information.

Maybe it got there during manufacturing?

Maybe Windows 7 uses it for something?