# Doubs and problems with dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm new to ubuntu and I need some help because i need it to work.

1) I got a dell inspiron 15r SE (or 7520). It got a ssd along with 1T disk. I'm not sure, but when I leave some space from C disk to install ubuntu (doesn't matter if its formatted or only free space), the ubuntu installer from bootable usb won't show this free space only the ssd. Anyone know why?

2) I got a external 1T disk that i use for backup. If I install ubuntu on this disk and uses it booting ubuntu from usb whenever I need it, does it uses all my available hardware? Because that seems a good solution. Will I be able to access my windows files from that bootable ubuntu usb stick?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating space from the C drive?

Comment: Many systems with your smaller SSD, are using Intel SRT which has the Windows hibernation on the SSD But that uses RAID which confuses the installer. You can remove SRT and RAID on drives and install Ubuntu and reimplement Intel SRT. If you install to external drive be sure to use Something else and select to install grub to external drive. Is external drive gpt partitioned as that would be required if you want to boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Post this with external plugged in from live installer. sudo parted -l

Comment: I created space using windows disk management.

Comment: oldfred, so basically i disable intel srt in eufi. goto ubuntu live, delete raid files, install ubuntu, and set up everything then go back and activate intel srt? or i dont need to disable it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing on the external disk will be just like installing on an internal disk. There should be no limitations on what hardware it can use. The only difference will be in speed. Depending on how the external disk is connected, it will not be as fast at booting or loading files as an internal disk. Connections like eSATA or USB 3.0 could be closer to the performance of internal disks.

You will only need to plug in the external drive when you want to boot Ubuntu or access it from Windows. Windows will not need the drive to boot, and even if you set up the BIOS to boot the external drive first, and the external drive is not attached, it should move on to the internal drive.

Comment: thanks man! if I dont get to make the dual boot i will surely use that option since the disk has an usb 3 connection =)

Comment: also, of if I install on the external hd, will I need to keep it plugged on pc to run windows? i have no idea because if i change the main boot and stuff. Or i can just plug it whenever i use ubuntu (just like a bootable usb with live ubuntu)?

Comment: I addressed your question in an edit.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much man! I will definitely use that option if I fail to install the dual boot without damaging my windows.

Answer (score 0):

**solution to 1**

The intel SRT used raid files to do something since the computer has both a hard drive and a flash ssd. The command

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
```

resolved the issue with no problems on the windows system. 
for more information: [I can't install Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15R at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182179/i-cant-install-ubuntu-on-my-dell-inspiron-15r-at-all)