# Can't install 14.10 to hard drive

Tags: system-installation, 14.10, partitioning

The Ubuntu installer simply will not show my drive in the installer menu. 
`fdisk -l` shows it, `gparted` works and I ran `partprobe`. I also tried rebooting, changing the SATA ports around and still no joy.

I can mount the drive and write to the `ext4` partition I made from the live boot, but the installer simply will not list it as an install target.

How can I install to this drive!?

[image: Screenshot for better diagnosis of issue]

Comment: Apparently it was because of a raid flag on the disk - as per:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/182179/i-cant-install-ubuntu-on-my-dell-inspiron-15r-at-all/186718#186718